# Dynamic cells size issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

i'm trying to create a table with many dynamic cells prototype
i'm using the 2 lines of codes in the viewDidLoad()

```
  Table.estimatedRowHeight = 171;
    Table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

however, when the cells need to be higher than 171, it stays 171, until i scroll down and up my tableview, then every cell takes it own really height

so what is the really problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, the location is not.

You should not be giving it in `viewDidLoad` but rather `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Try that, it should work. Cheers!

Comment: it work will, but when i go to another page and then go back to this viewcontroller, the size of the cells change to a height of 44 maybe. so i resolve this problem by reloading my table in the viewwillappear

Comment: Yes, in such a scenario you have to reload the table, because the conditions would be unknown, lets say you rotated the screen and went back to the self sizing cells view controller, you need to reload to determine the apt height

Comment: oh, but in fact, now i saw another problem,when i go back to this viewcontroller , the app crashes and the error message is : " internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head"
and xcode highlight  this line of code : cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! itemCellTableViewCell

Comment: Actually please re-structure your code in a way that whatever initializations that you need to reuse after back-navigation, you need to do them in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad` like `itemCellTableViewCell`

Answer (score 1):

The `UITableView` asks you for the hight:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```